# Access Next.js client state on the server

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to fetch dynamic data in my Next.js app using the `getServerSideProps` function. The request must contain a token, which is stored client-side, to authenticate the user on the backend.

I've tried the following:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
  const data = await axios.get("/data", { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }});
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

But I get `ReferenceError : window is not defined`, which makes sense because the request is being made on the server and the `window` object doesn't exist there (it only exists on the client).

Can I access client state in `getServerSideProps` or store next state on the server? If not, looks like the only way to do this would be to make the request client-side.

Comment: The best way is to store token in cookies, so it will be available on client and server side

Comment: `window` and `localStorage` both exist in the browser, not in a node application where the server side rendering is happening. The client side code should be sending the JWT with the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use cookies instead. Because getServersideProps happen in server-side rendering, so window or localStorage cannot access. Use cookies and js-cookie library to set and get token.